# Optimizer LBFGS OWLQN implementation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am looking for documentation about implementation of parallel LBFGS and OWLQN algorithms in Spark 1.6 ML library.

I found this page for 1.6: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ml-advanced.html but nothing about parallelization

For the 2.0: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/ml-advanced.html but still nothing about parallelization

Finally, I read the code [link1]. The method

```
def train(dataset: DataFrame): LogisticRegressionModel
```

seems optimize the model using Breeze but I don't find where spark functions are called (map, flatMap, reduce,...).

In the code [link2], map is used to compute sub-gradients that are reduced to compute gradient.

Thanks

Comment: link1: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala

Comment: link2: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkLR.scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, Spark uses the Breeze LBFGS and OWLQN optimization algorithms and provides them each with a way to compute the gradient of the cost function at each iteration.

Spark's `LogisticRegression` class, for instance, utilizes a `LogisticCostFun` class which extends Breeze's `DiffFunction` trait. This cost function class implements the `calculate` abstract method which has the signature:

```scala
override def calculate(coefficients: BDV[Double]): (Double, BDV[Double])
```

The calculate method utilizes a `LogisticAggregator` class, which is where the real work is done. The aggregation class defines two important methods:

```scala
def add(instance: Instance): this.type // the gradient update equation is hard-coded here
def merge(other: LogisticAggregator): this.type // just adds other's gradient to the current gradient
```

The add method defines a way to update the gradient after adding a single data point, and the merge method defines a way to combine two separate aggregators. This class is shipped to the executors, used to aggregate each data partition, and then used to combine all the partition aggregators into a single aggregator. That final aggregator instance holds the cumulative gradient for the current iteration, and is used to update the coefficients on the driver node. This process is controlled by a call to `treeAggregate` in the `LogisticCostFun` class:

```scala
val logisticAggregator = {
  val seqOp = (c: LogisticAggregator, instance: Instance) => c.add(instance)
  val combOp = (c1: LogisticAggregator, c2: LogisticAggregator) => c1.merge(c2)

  instances.treeAggregate(
    new LogisticAggregator(coeffs, numClasses, fitIntercept, featuresStd, featuresMean)
  )(seqOp, combOp)
}
```

You can think of it a bit more simply like this: Breeze implements several different optimization methods (e.g. LBFGS, OWLQN) and only requires you to tell the optimization method how to compute the gradient. Spark tells the Breeze algorithm how to compute the gradient via the `LogisticCostFun` class. `LogisticCostFun` just says to ship out a `LogisticAggregator` instance to each partition, collect gradient updates, and then ship them back to be combined on the driver.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.